# MethodNotAllowedHttpException (lumen) while making request with axios

Tags: php, reactjs, axios, lumen, lumen-5.4

Created a route for inserting todo in lumen , its working perfectly using postman but in my react application request sending with axios , it getting error

```
this.apiUrl = 'http://lumenback.dev/createTodo';

axios.post(this.apiUrl, {
  todo: this.state.todo,
  todo_date: this.props.curDate
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

[image]

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is not accepting the Cross domain requests I guess.

Here is an answer [Lumen API CORS Ajax 405 Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46996130/lumen-api-cors-ajax-405-method-not-allowed/47012740#47012740)  I wrote to setup Cors and make it working with React and Lumen 5.5.

See if this can help.

I cannot comment so writing this solution here.

Comment: after adding belowe code fixedmy problem

Route::options(
    '/{any:.*}',
    [
        'middleware' => ['CorsMiddleware'],
        function (){
            return response(['status' => 'success']);
        }
    ]
);

Answer (score 0):

This is a stab in the dark, but have you tried setting the headers on axios first?

Insert this before your post command:

 `axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";`

Comment: no luck , still getting error

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405

Comment: Then the error is most likely being thrown by Laravel due to the route configuration. Heave you checked this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677198/laravel-5-method-not-allowed-http-exception-in-route-collection-php-line-201 ? Specifically, have you perhaps configured the route for a GET but not a POST?

Comment: i think it is related the cors

Comment: but i added the core middleware too  that why my get request is working, but not in post request

Comment: What happens if you try using CURL to test your endpoint directly: 


curl -X POST http://lumenback.dev/createTodo -d '{todo: dummyData, todo_date: dummyData}'
  
Do you get an error?

Comment: hello whats the solution on you? i got this too with axios