# MethodNotAllowedHttpException error?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working on an Android laravel application, but I have this road problem ?? `Route::post('register','Api\Auth\RegistrationController@register');`

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 : Method Not Allowed Http Exception in Route Collection.php line 201:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677198/laravel-5-method-not-allowed-http-exception-in-route-collection-php-line-201)

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you are trying to make a GET request on POST-only route. Check your route file.

Comment: no problem that it is a post request and even in list route it's just but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Have you put

```
protected $except = [
    'Api/*'
];
```

in your `VerifyCsrfToken.php` file? As far as I know, APIs typically use tokens to authenticate users and do not maintain session state between requests. So try this and check your headers and body for API post request.